# C# TCP Socket callback not returning bytes for first sent message

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a console app that listens for client socket connections and the packets being sent. Once a packet is sent, it outputs the length of the packet. I am trying to create a bit more organization to my application and keep some of these actions within their own objects. However, I have run into a small issue where the first message comes back as 0, but the rest of them work just fine.

I have an object that handles the data being received:

```
public class Receiver : IDisposable
{
    private byte[] _buffer;
    public Receiver(byte[] buffer)
    {
        this._buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void DoWork(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        int bufferSize = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);
        byte[] packet = new byte[bufferSize];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, packet, packet.Length);

        // Handle the packet
        ushort packetLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, 0);

        Console.WriteLine("Packet received... Length: {0}", packetLength);

        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, this.DoWork, clientSocket);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

An object that handles incoming connections:

```
public class Connector : IDisposable
{
    private Socket _socket;
    private Receiver _receiver;
    private byte[] _buffer;
    public Connector(Socket socket, Receiver receiver, byte[] buffer)
    {
        this._socket = socket;
        this._receiver = receiver;
        this._buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _socket.BeginAccept(this.HandleAcceptedCallback,null);

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    private void HandleAcceptedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = _socket.EndAccept(result);
        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, _receiver.DoWork, clientSocket);
        this.DoWork();
    }
}
```

And then my console object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        using (Receiver receiver = new Receiver(buffer))
        using (Connector connector = new Connector(socket, receiver, buffer))
        {
            socket.Bind(11000);
            socket.Listen(500);
            connector.DoWork();

            while (true)
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to play around with different approaches and have found out that if I move the `DoWork` method from the `Receiver` object into the `Connector` object and wire the callbacks up there, it all works fine.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me where I am going wrong, or why this is not practical? I am new to using sockets and apologize for any misunderstandings.

Comment: i suspect your issues is that `clientSocket` goes out of scope at the end of `HandleAcceptedCallback`. I would have a container of (list, dictionary, ...) of connected clients;

Comment: @pm100 : perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean here... I added a new private list of `Socket` in my `Connector` object. and added the `clientSocket` to the list at the end of `HandleAcceptedCallback` and still nothing. Any ideas where I am going wrong here?